# How to show a hidden swf movie?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, mouseover

I have 2 swf in my html page which are video and popup. When mouse over to video.swf the hidden popup.swf will show and play.

```
<body>

<object id="video" class="video" width="300" height="250">
<param name="movie" value="thumbnail.swf">
<embed src="thumbnail.swf"  quality="high" width="300" height="250" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"/> 
</object>
<img class="image" src="300x250.jpg">
<object id="popup" class="popup" width="790" height="290">
<param name="movie" value="790x290.swf">
<embed src="790x290.swf" width="300" height="250"> </embed>
</object>

<script>
document.getElementById("video").onmouseover = over;

(function over()
{
 alert("mouseovertest");
});

</script>
```

The mouseover on video.swf is working fine but Im not sure how to make the popup.swf shows and play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this in your `<script>` section:

```
document.getElementById("popup").onmouseover = over;
```